# Windows 10 not booting, even though data is intact, how to recover

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, boot

I currently have 3 physical disks on my windows home computer. They accumulated over the years. Each time there was an issue with boot, I got a new disk and installed a new windows.

So the situation right now is like this:

[image]

- Disk 0: WDC (non-SSD) -> drive C(windows 7)
- Disk 1: Sandisk (ssd) -> drive F(windows?) + G(no windows)
- Disk 2: Corsair (ssd) -> drive E(windows7 ultimate + windows 10)
- Disk 3: external HD for backup.

Issue started today, after I made a restart, instead of booting from the windows 10 Corsair disk like it usually does, the computer booted from the WDC disk.

Data is ok in all disks: I can see everything that is inside the Corsair disk when from the windows 7 user of the WDC disk.

When I reboot the computer, I see only the WDC and Sandisk in the splash screen. I dont see the Corsair. But when I get into the BIOS, I can see the Corsair in the list.

I tried switching to the Corsair disk on BIOS, but it tries to load the windows 7 ultimate (and get stuck on windows load, not getting to login screen).

Even if I physically disconnect the other disks and leave only the Corsair, it doesn't see the windows 10 when booting. It only loads the windows 7 ultimate.

Anyway to recover the windows 10 boot on the Corsair, so that to avoid the painful process of reinstalling all the programs from scratch?

Comment: A common mistake when people buy a new disc and install a fresh Windows is that they don't correctly change the boot order in BIOS before installing Windows. Therefore best is to disconnect all old discs before installing new Windows so you can be sure the one disc contains everything needed for booting and Windows does not use partitions on other disks.

Answer (score 0):

You have written: **Disk 2: Corsair (ssd) -> drive E(windows7 ultimate + windows 10)**. Are you sure on on this disk are 2 Operating Systems.

1. There is just one partition.
2. The *System Reserved* partition is just 100 MB. Usualy Windsows 7 creates it with this size, Windows 10 creates a 450 MB.
   Connect Disk 1 and Disk 2 (I think Windows 10 is installed on Disk 1), doesn't matter which windows is loading, you can use **msconfig** to see your installed OS and change the boot order.

Type msconfig in the Start search field and then press Enter to open the System Configuration, in Boot tab select which operating system you want to set as default, click Apply and then OK to close the dialog, Reboot.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I tried using a USB rescue disk. The idea was to see if it can detect the windows 10 on the Corsair disk, and then try to repair it. However, I was only able to see windows 7 using the the rescue tool. 
I then rebooted, and it loaded the windows 10.